# Open activity from notification Jelly Bean issue

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Just to make it short:

**what I need** is open an activity, start a countdown, minimize, launch a notification when timer goes to 0 and by tapping the notification go back to the previous state of the activity without creating a new one

**what I have** is this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, intent, 0);
```

It works perfectly for android <4.2 but when runs on Jelly Bean, it opens a new instance of the Activity.
It seems that Jelly Bean does not recognize  none of the flags Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP

How can I make it run for 4.2+ ?

Comment: I am not sure, but what about to set your activity launchMode="singleTop"

Comment: Nice, Georgy, it works. If you post this as an answer to the question instead of a comment, i'll indicate as the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set your activity launch mode as

```
launchMode="singleTop"
```